# How do I align the text correctly in html

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align the text to right like the first row but the second row keeps spilling below the image. How do I make the text properly aligned no matter the number of rows?

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="A_3"><i id="I_4"></i></a><span id="SPAN_5">     
</span>
<h5 id="H5_6">Payroll</h5>
    <p id="P_7">
        What what everytrksdjfsdf sdmnb fsdmnb sd xcmnvb xcm mbb mvcn bcvxmcnbv</p>
```

check the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yagipasapa/edit?html,css,output) please:

Edit: I see that Safari(1) is displaying this correctly but Google Chrome(2) isn't.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this out?http://jsbin.com/zosidusife/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I'm on chrome and it looks correct to me? Maybe you should include some pictures of what you are experiencing vs what it should actually look like?

Comment: apply text-align:justify than try

Comment: added some pictures to explain myself and updated the jsbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
margin: 0px 25px 80px;
```

to the A_3 element (the bootstrap circle)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `box-sizing: border-box;` from both the elements. Also add `width: 457.5px;` to `#H5_6`

Check below code.

```css
#A_3 {
  float: right;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 65px;
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  font: normal normal normal normal 35px / 50px'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
}
/*#A_3*/

#H5_6 {
  text-align: right;
  width: 457.5px;
}
/*#H5_6*/

#P_7 {
  color: rgb(95, 95, 95);
  height: 56px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 457.5px;
  font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 30.8px'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
}
/*#P_7*/
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" id="A_3"><i id="I_4"></i></a><span id="SPAN_5"></span>
<h5 id="H5_6">
   Payroll
  </h5>
<p id="P_7">
  What what everytrksdjfsdf sdmnb fsdmnb sd xcmnvb xcm mbb mvcn bcvxmcnbv What what everytrksdjfsdf sdmnb fsdmnb sd xcmnvb xcm mbb mvcn bcvxmcnbv
</p>
```

Comment: hm, I updated it without the border-box and box-sizing but it still shows the same in chrome, any other thoughts?

Comment: Also add `width: 457.5px;` to `#H5_6`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/qigitoyeyo/1/edit?html,css,output

You can just set "margin-right:115px;" on the <p> tag.

That way you don't have to manually set the height and width.